# If statement seems to be ignored

Tags: php, if-statement, pdo, http-headers

I have an if statement, as soon as it is true I will redirect to another page. It does not seem to work for me.

```
<?php 
    require 'includes/config.php';

    session_start(); 

    if ( !empty($_POST['username'] && $_POST['password']) ){
    $gebruikersnaam = $_POST['username'];
    $wachtwoord = $_POST['password'];
    }

    try{
    $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=project_sync', $config['DB_USERNAME'], $config['DB_PASSWORD']);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM employee WHERE gebruikersnaam = :gebruikersnaam');
    // Bind and Execute
    $stmt->execute(array(
            'gebruikersnaam' => $gebruikersnaam
        ));
    // Fetch Result
    while($result = $stmt->fetch()){
      if ($gebruikersnaam == $result['gebruikersnaam'] && $wachtwoord == $result['wachtwoord']){
    header('Location: http://localhost/project_sync2/dashboard.php');
    exit(); 
    }else{
    header('Location: http://localhost/project_sync2/index.php?set=loginerror');
    exit();
        set=loginerror';

    }
    }
    }catch (PDOExeption $e) {
        echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
?>
```

Can Anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You should be getting a syntax error from the first line. You can't have an expression in the arguments to `empty()`, its argument has to be a single variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be:

```
if ( !empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['password']) ){
```

From the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php):

> Prior to PHP 5.5, **empty()** only supports variables; anything else will result in a parse error.

Comment: Gosh I cant believe I overlooked this. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Replace you condition with this:

```
if ( !empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['password']) ){
[...]
```